# Algorithms of compare multiple fields

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I have a table `info`

```
CREATE TABLE `info` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `phone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The comparable fields are name, email and phone.

My compare rule is: any two of the three fields equal then the two records equal.

So my question is what is the most efficient way of implements this feature.

P.S. I can add extra fields if needs.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL returns 1 for true and 0 for false.

```
Select * From info 
WHERE (name = 'name') + (email = 'email') + (phone = 'phone') > 1
```

Comment: I think OP wants to create a constraint at table creation itself

Comment: With this `where` clause, how to add an index to improve search performance?

Comment: read this for more details of index http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html @ChongYoung

Comment: @RahulTripathi yeah, i  was wondering  if there are some algorithms efficient like bloom filter.

Comment: @Rahautos I'm not sure mysql can use multi-columns index when executing this `where` clause?

Comment: @Rahautos the where clause should be greater and equal than 2.

Comment: yes is  greater and equal than 2 or greater than 1 :)- @ChongYoung